# Gridview Table not visible, html does not render

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that is bound to an objectdatasource.  It is getting data, the data is in the html markup - I just can't see it!

Here is the default.aspx:

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="memorywell_2._Default" %>

Memorywell Information Services

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="resumesource" runat="server" SelectMethod="FetchAllGigs" EnablePaging="false" 
 DataObjectTypeName="memorywell_2DataModel.Resume" TypeName="memorywell_2DataModel.Resume">   
</asp:ObjectDataSource>    
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="resumesource" AllowPaging="false" PageSize="10">
     <EmptyDataTemplate>
        No data for your query.</EmptyDataTemplate>
    <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
               Description: <%# Eval("Description") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

</form>
```

here is the html from "view page source" on my browser:

Memorywell Information Services

```
    <div>
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="GridView1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>
               Description: (Contract)  Maintain 4 websites including a national site that receives 80,000 hits per month.  Develop new sites and custom modules in C# and MS SQL for DotNetNuke content management system.  Developing new internationally targeted community site that includes custom C# modules for product reviews.                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the HTML you provided you should have a table with one cell and the text inside (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RqkEy/) with your HTML)
Check if your table is inside a container (maybe some DIV) that is hidden.

Comment: Thanks.  You're right.  I just deleted the original form and re-created it and it worked.  This was some Visual Studio 2008 bug.  Thanks for looking.